# validating email address which contains non-english (UTF-8) character in Java

Tags: java, regex, email-validation

i am having fallowing email id

```
闪闪发光@闪闪发光.com
```

i need to validate this type of email at server side so that user can not enter this type of email..
 i have solved similar problem in javascript by using below regex-

```
/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/gi
```

But. unable to do same thing in java.Please help me guys.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What was the problem? Java Regex Pattern and Matcher should do...

Comment: Are you sure that you want exclude UTF domain names?

Comment: yes, i know but i am not getting how to implement this..

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html = It's beyond stupid.

Comment: UTF-8 is allowed in email addresses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java regular expression pattern `(?i)[-a-z0-9+_][-a-z0-9+_.]*@[-a-z0-9][-a-z0-9.]*\\.[a-z]{2,6}` should suffice.  Here's what the pattern means:

```
(?i)            # Case insensitive flag
[-a-z0-9+_]     # First character
[-a-z0-9+_.]*   # Zero or more characters
@               # Literal '@' character
[-a-z0-9]       # Match a single character
[-a-z0-9.]*     # Match zero or more characters
\.              # Literal '.' character
[a-z]{2,6}      # Match 2 through 6 alpha characters
```

The following test code ...

```
final String ps =
        "(?i)[-a-z0-9+_][-a-z0-9+_.]*@[-a-z0-9][-a-z0-9.]*\\.[a-z]{2,6}";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
for (String s : new String[] {"foo@bar.COM", "+foo@bar.COM",
        "-foo@bar.COM", "fo_o@bar.COM", "f.oo@bar.COM", "a@b.cdefgh",
        "3@4.com", "3@4.5.6-7.8.com", ".foo@bar.com", "a@b.cdefghi",
        "闪闪发光@闪闪发光.com"})
{
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Success: " + s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fail: " + s);
    }
}
```

... will output:

```
Success: foo@bar.COM
Success: +foo@bar.COM
Success: -foo@bar.COM
Success: fo_o@bar.COM
Success: f.oo@bar.COM
Success: a@b.cdefgh
Success: 3@4.com
Success: 3@4.5.6-7.8.com
Fail: .foo@bar.com
Fail: a@b.cdefghi
Fail: 闪闪发光@闪闪发光.com
```

By using the `Matcher.matches()` method, you don't need to include the `^` start-of-line or `$` end-of-line boundary matching constructs since `Matcher.matches()` will match on the whole string.

Comment: Why do you want this "Fail: a@b.cdefghi" to fail? Can't that be a completely valid internal email adress like: root@lcal1ap.prelife (the machine I'm working on right now ;D )

Comment: @Angel O'Sphere: The OP limits the top level domain to 2 through 6 characters; more than 6 characters should fail.  I presume this is because the longest TLD in this [list of TLDs](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) is `museum` ... 6 characters.

Comment: @Dan Cruz-thanks for explanatory answer.if i don't want to limit top level domain to 6 then i need to to do this-`(?i)[-a-z0-9+_][-a-z0-9+_.]*@[-a-z0-9][-a-z0-9.]*\\.[a-z]*` or something else.

Comment: @Vivek: I would use `\\.[a-z]+` at the end of the pattern instead of `\\.[a-z]*`.  The `+` will ensure you have at least one character after the `.`; whereas `*` could leave you with an email address like  `a@b.`.

Comment: Just  to update, today TLD can be more than 6 chars and more are created annually so any assumption of TLD length will probably fail eventually.

Answer (score 0):

[Update] Sorry for the js code. Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


    public class EmailValidator{

          private Pattern pattern;
          private Matcher matcher;

          private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
                       "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@
                       [A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

          public EmailValidator(){
              pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
          }

          /**
           * Validate hex with regular expression
           * @param hex hex for validation
           * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
           */
          public boolean validate(final String hex){

              matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
              return matcher.matches();

          }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like Java-Code to me!?